# Sum Cookie value when I click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have an input text and a button where a I put a number and storage this value in a Cookie using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) clicking a button.

```
<input id="number" type="text" value="0">
<button id="send" type="button">SEND</button>
```

I want to sum each time I enter a number and show the result in an alert, so I tried in this way:

**Jquery:**

```
$("#number").keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13){
    $("#send").click();
  }
});

$("#send").click(function(){ 
   var number= 0;
   number+= parseInt($("#number").val(),10);
   Cookies.set("numw", number);
});

var numw = Cookies.get("numw");
alert("Total: "+numw);
```

But this still showing the first number I sent.

I would like some help.

Comment: So, all I see you doing is setting the cookie on click.  I don't see you doing a sum any where.  Also as you have it, the alert would not happen upon the send click.

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with another way of get it but it's still the same.

Comment: You are initializing your `number` to zero each click.  You're not trying to get the stored value from the cookie, if it exists, to add to.

Comment: well `var number= 0;` resets the value every time.... I doubt you want to do that. My guess it should be adding it to `numw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add the number like:

```
$("#send").click(function(){ 
    //var number= 0;
    var numwTemp = Cookies.get("numw");
    //number = parseInt($("#number").val(),10)) + parseInt(numwTemp, 10);
    var number = parseInt($("#number").val(),10)) + parseInt(numwTemp || "0", 10);
    Cookies.set("numw", number);
});

var numw = Cookies.get("numw");
alert("Total: "+numw);
```

Comment: I update the answer with @Taplar suggestion, which is a very valid point. Thanks Taplar.

Comment: You might also want to safe guard against the input field being blank, or containing nothing but spaces.